# Zoom to a specific location in ArcMap Viewer window using ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects

I'm trying to find out how to open Viewer window (menu Windows->Viewer in ArcMap) programmatically and zoom it to a specific location. This is how I can open it:

```cs
IDataWindowFactory dwf = new MapViewerWindowFactoryClass();
IDataWindow dw = dwf.Create(mArcMap);   // typeof mArcMap is IApplication
```

and to show it:

```cs
dw.Show(true);
```

but I can't find a way to set the initial extent when opening the viewer window or at least how to change it after it is loaded.

[image]

---

Problem solved by using [IMapInsetWindow](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMapInsetWindow_Interface/000v000000w0000000/) interface.

```cs
IDataWindow2 dw = this.createDataWindow(new MapViewerWindowFactoryClass());
IMapInsetWindow mapInset = dw as IMapInsetWindow;
mapInset.MapInset.VisibleBounds = extent;

dw.Show(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is some code in VBA that shows how to set the extent of the viewer window to the current map. The key interface is [IMapInsetWindow](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMapInsetWindow_Interface/000v000000w0000000/) which gives you access to the [IMapInset2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMapInset2_Interface/0012000008t1000000/) and it's read/write properties.

```vb
Public Sub updateMapView()
    ' Get map document
    Dim pMXDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMXDoc = ThisDocument

    ' Get Map
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXDoc.FocusMap

    ' Get the active view of the map
    Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
    Set pActiveView = pMap

    ' Get extent of map
    Dim pEnvelope As IEnvelope
    Set pEnvelope = pActiveView.Extent

    ' Get Application
    Dim pApp As IApplication
    Set pApp = Application

    ' Create Factory
    Dim pDataWindowFactory As IDataWindowFactory
    Set pDataWindowFactory = New MapViewerWindowFactory

    ' Create MapViewer Window and open it
    Dim pDataWindow As IDataWindow2
    Set pDataWindow = pDataWindowFactory.Create(pApp)
    pDataWindow.Show True

    ' Cast DataWindow into MapInsetWindow
    Dim pMapInsetWindow As IMapInsetWindow
    Set pMapInsetWindow = pDataWindow

    ' Set the extent of the InsetWindow to the current map Extent
    pMapInsetWindow.MapInset.VisibleBounds = pEnvelope

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, thats great! I actually saw a similar answer but thought that IMapInsetWindow class is used only for managing the Magnifier window and not for the Viewer window, which I want to use.